# Sort ajax response object by values

Tags: javascript, sorting

In one of my .net core 3.1 app's razor pages I am creating a selection list dynamically using the response of an Ajax call.
The response is a key-value pairs object like this:

```
{
 1162: 'Κινητήρας',
 1163: 'Εξαρτήματα',
 1164: 'Λεπτομέρειες',
 1165: 'Λίπανση'
}
```

I need to sort the object by the values before creating the dropdown and still keep its key-value format. The result should be:

```
{
 1163: 'Εξαρτήματα',
 1162: 'Κινητήρας',
 1164: 'Λεπτομέρειες',
 1165: 'Λίπανση'
}
```

This is my code with the latest attempt, which works with the values but looses the keys.

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: `/characteristics/GetGroupsByLocale?locale=${locale}`,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        var x = Object.values(data).sort();

                        //var keysSorted = Object.keys(data)
                        //    .sort(function (a, b) { return data[a] - data[b] })
                        //    .map(key => data[key]);

                        console.log(x);
                        

                        grpDrpdwn.append(
                            $('<option>', { value: "" }).text('Select a Group')
                        );
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                            grpDrpdwn.append(
                                $('<option>', { value: key })
                                    .text(value)
                            );
                        });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        grpDrpdwn.append(
                            $('<option>', { value: "" }).text('No Groups available')
                        );
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You can't. Objects with numeric keys are always sorted by keys. Use a different data structure, like a `Map` or a list of key-values pairs.

Comment: The best approach is to store it as an array of object: which you can dictate manual sort order.

Comment: I ended up converting the object to an array as @terry suggested and then sorted it by values.